# Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException

Tags: spring-boot, mockmvc, spring-boot-test

A simple test on my RestController is failing miserably.

Setup - SpringBoot 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT with the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    runtime('com.h2database:h2')
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

The City Object:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class City {
    private Long id;
    private String city;

    public City(Long id, String city) {
        this.id = id;
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

The Controller Class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cities")
public class CityController {
    @GetMapping
    public List<City> findAllCities() {
        return Collections.singletonList(new City(1L, "Rancho Cordova"));
    }
}
```

The CityControllerTest class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = CityController.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class CityControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testGetAllCities() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/cities")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Exception I get when I run Test:

```
.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.Collections$SingletonList
```

What am I missing???????

Answer (score 0):

My bad. The mistake I made above is that I gave the Controller for the classes parameter. Rather, the code should have looked like this:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = CityApplication.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
```

Comment: you didn't even mention your CityApplication class in the question, that makes it quite impossible to debug as such. Voting to close as "cannot reproduce".